# Html To WordPress CSS Element Not Showing Correctly

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have a static HTML site which I've converted to WordPress.  The problem is that my site is always aligned to left (only in WordPress) even though I've tried several solutions like this:

```
body{
  margin: auto;
}
```

The original html page is centered with no problem.

Eg:

```
#Logo { 
  left: 20px; 
  top: 29px; 
  position: absolute; 
  width: 181px;
  height: 91px;
  z-index:163;
}
```

`left: 20px;` should put the logo in the position I want in the HTML page but in WordPress, it is aligned to the left.

Comment: could be anything...examine the css rules applied in chrome inspector and see what rule is causing it....also check the parent divs widths etc.

Answer (score 0):

The wordpress page has its own stylesheets most likely. If you inspect the page, and delete those style sheets coming from wordpress, you should see the culprit that is affecting your page.

You will either need to edit their CSS, or use !important in your own if their CSS is not editable by you.

Answer (score 0):

you should use https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-custom-css/ 
that plug-in allows An easy-to-use WordPress Plugin to add custom CSS styles that override Plugin and Theme default styles. This plugin is designed to meet the needs of administrators who would like to add their own CSS to their WordPress website.

Layers is another one  http://www.layerswp.com/2015/09/this-is-by-far-the-fastest-way-to-edit-css-on-any-wordpress-site/

sorry forgot, if you already use Jetpack, you can do it there

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Guys For Your Interest
But I found out that the problem was caused by a removed div.